# Failed to remove package protection with error 0x80131940

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm trying to open a password protected package in SQL Server BIDs and I keep getting the following error message each time I pu in the correct password:

`Failed to remove package protection with error 0x80131940 "(null)"`

This occurs in the `CPaqckage::LoadFromXML` method.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same problem and discovered that caps-lock was on. Typing the correct password with caps-lock on gives the error message "Failed to remove package protection with error 0x80131940 "(null)", whereas typing the wrong password gives the "The password you have entered is incorrect" message. Very misleading but simple to fix.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you thought you had the right password but that you really didn't.

I recently ran into this problem. I know you posted a long time ago but I could not find an answer when I ran into the same situation.  Turns out I had the wrong password when I thought I had it right (I was not the one who created the package).

I had assumed that since some wrong passwords produced a `wrong password` error message that I must have had the right password with the one that did not produce a `wrong password` message - it turns out that different wrong passwords can return different error messages when opening a password encrypted SSIS package!

Very odd. At any rate, after finally getting a hold of the original developer, and getting the correct password, I was able to open the package just fine.

For what its worth I would never recommend encrypting the whole package with password, sensitive data maybe, but not the entire package.

Comment: Same problem. Have just encrypted project with one password and package with practically same, forgetting one symbol. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I just received the same error. My issue was targeting SQL Server 2017 instead of SQL Server 2016 (Project > Propertied > Configuration Properties > General > Deployment Target Version > TargetServerVersion)

Comment: same problem, same solution. SSIS Project was targeting SQL Server 2019, version of SQL server is 2016. After updating the project, project works

Answer (score 0):

I got this message running a package built on vs 2017 enterprise on my laptop.   In this situation people always fuss about your password.   If you can get into the package with visual studio, you know your password.  I was setting encryptAllWithPassword at the solution and package level.   It was only failing with this message on my laptop as dtexec.  When I moved the package to azure it ran with the /DECRYPT statement.   So if you're only testing in one environment and it fails, try it in another environment (azure or server environment) and it might work.